# Should the array be sql safe in insert operation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Should the array be sql safe in insert operation like that:

DB::table('table')->insert($data);

Should the $data array be sql safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Query Builder docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#introduction):

> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

So, if you don't use raw queries, you don't need to worry about data safety.